# Axios promise is not throwing error in vue method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, axios, vuex

As the title says, I have a problem catching an error in a Vue method `getTodo`.
Click on **Set incorrect url** and then on **Get Todo**, you can see there is an error in the store as expected, but in Vue when the `getTodo` promise's `then` is executed, there's no error. If you select **Set correct url** then it works fine.
Console logs should look like this:

```
error on store  
error on vue
```

**JavaScript** and **HTML** below:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        todo: '',
        msg: '',
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/test',
        correct: false
    },
    mutations: {
        setTodo(state, payload) {
            state.todo = payload;
        },
        setMsg(state, payload) {
            state.msg = payload;
        },
        setCorrect(state) {
            state.url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
            state.correct = true;
        },
        setIncorrect(state) {
            state.url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/test';
            state.correct = false;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        getTodo({ state, commit }) {
            return axios.get(state.url)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('success on store');
                    commit('setMsg', 'success on store');
                    commit('setTodo', response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('error on store');
                    commit('setMsg', 'error on store');
                });
        }
    }
})
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: ''
    },
    computed: {
        todo() {
            return store.state.todo;
        },
        msg() {
            return store.state.msg;
        },
        correctUrl() {
            return store.state.correct;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getTodo() {
            store.dispatch('getTodo').then(() => {
                console.log('success on vue');
                this.message = 'success on vue'
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.log('error on vue');
                this.message = 'error on vue';
            });
        },
        setCorrect() {
            store.commit('setCorrect');
        },
        setIncorrect() {
            store.commit('setIncorrect');
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
        <p>{{ todo }}</p>
        <p>Correct url: {{ correctUrl }}</p>
        <button @click="getTodo">Get Todo</button>
        <button @click="setCorrect">Set correct url</button>
        <button @click="setIncorrect">Set incorrect url</button>
    </div>
    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.0.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-throw the error after catching it in your `getTodo` action ..

```
actions: {
        getTodo({ state, commit }) {
            return axios.get(state.url)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('success on store');
                    commit('setMsg', 'success on store');
                    commit('setTodo', response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('error on store');
                    commit('setMsg', 'error on store');
                    throw error;
                });
        }
}
```

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        todo: '',
        msg: '',
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/test',
        correct: false
    },
    mutations: {
        setTodo(state, payload) {
            state.todo = payload;
        },
        setMsg(state, payload) {
            state.msg = payload;
        },
        setCorrect(state) {
            state.url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
            state.correct = true;
        },
        setIncorrect(state) {
            state.url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/test';
            state.correct = false;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        getTodo({ state, commit }) {
            return axios.get(state.url)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('success on store');
                    commit('setMsg', 'success on store');
                    commit('setTodo', response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('error on store');
                    commit('setMsg', 'error on store');
                    throw error;
                });
        }
    }
})
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: ''
    },
    computed: {
        todo() {
            return store.state.todo;
        },
        msg() {
            return store.state.msg;
        },
        correctUrl() {
            return store.state.correct;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getTodo() {
            store.dispatch('getTodo').then(() => {
                console.log('success on vue');
                this.message = 'success on vue'
            }).catch((e) => {
                console.log('error on vue');
                this.message = 'error on vue';
            });
        },
        setCorrect() {
            store.commit('setCorrect');
        },
        setIncorrect() {
            store.commit('setIncorrect');
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
        <p>{{ todo }}</p>
        <p>Correct url: {{ correctUrl }}</p>
        <button @click="getTodo">Get Todo</button>
        <button @click="setCorrect">Set correct url</button>
        <button @click="setIncorrect">Set incorrect url</button>
    </div>
    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.0.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works as i expected, but i have two more questions. May i have problems in future using that approach? For example if i want to build nested API calls. Second question is about using js promises with axios or it doesn't make any sense?

Comment: @hafer [Re-throwing](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining#rethrowing) an error in a promise chain is a common pattern. You just have to make sure the [error is handled properly](https://hackernoon.com/promises-and-error-handling-4a11af37cb0e) in the latter stages in the chain.

Comment: As for axios you do know it's promise based and it's a well designed library so unless there's some pressing need to mix in your own promises I would refrain from doing that lest you unknowingly fall into some [anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) in the process.